# TFS Tasks to JIRA Tasks

Tags: tfs, jira

We are looking to copy tfs tasks and bugs to JIRA. It would be great if we could copy the user stories and the time spent on each task also copied over to JIRA from TFS!

Is there any tool for this or a suggestion to create a custom application which will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Good timing.  Atlassian just posted a youtube video on this yesterday.

[From TFS to Jira](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHgW-ocvwXg)

Essentially, you export from TFS what you need into an Excel,convert to CSV format and then use the Import External Project from Jira.  Choose Microsoft TFS from the Import Wizard, select your CSV and then map fields from TFS into the new ones in Jira.  You'll have to set up your links between tasks and stories again though.

Comment: I dont have an option to import :/

Comment: Does your user account have the JIRA Administrators global permission? https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/importing-data-from-csv-185729516.html

Comment: I'd probably get an admin to do it but you can check if you have enough permissions to do bulk create from csv - https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/creating-issues-using-the-csv-importer-636420874.html